# Does 両親ともに健在とは限らない。mean "Both of my parents aren't alive."?

Tags: meaning

This is a sentence from the Tanaka corpus, I would have thought that it means "I have a parent that has passed away.".

I'm asking that because the Tanaka corpus contains some mistakes so I think it may be the case here but I'm not sure(some people say that this sentence doesn't mean anyone is dead).

Comment: ～とは限らない means "not necessarily ~". So the sentence in question means "It does not necessarily mean that (someone's) parents are both alive."

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8253/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55809/9831

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, "〜とは限らない" means that there is not a 100% probability that the thing is true.
However, it is used when there is no guarantee that the thing is 100% sure, but there is a slight probability that the thing is true.

In this case, it means that there is not a 100% probability that the parents are still alive and well.

In other words, **there is no guarantee that the 〇〇 will happen.**

Example①：（Often used in Manga.）
・彼が絶対に生きているとは限らない

Example2②（when you are not sure if the bus will be on time）
・バスが時間通りに来るとは限らない

Answer (score 0):

It's correcting someone or himself's say because that might be too early to judge that.
Like, when you look at a shore and see a storm coming soon, but you shouldn't know about a shore which is located in hundreds miles away.
I think the phrase とは限らない is used in a case when you're not clear about that.
Sometimes it'd sound too cautious.